# Android: add buttons to a preference screen

Tags: android, button, preferenceactivity

The thing is...I want to use PreferenceActivity to add a new row in my custom list view. So my preference ativity will consist of a few EditTextPreferences, my custom TimePickerPreference and a coulpe of ListPreferences... Like this: http://www.google.com/help/hc/images/android/android_ug/168567.5.png . The question is how they added buttons on the bottom? And.. is it possible to use OnClickListener for obtaining inputed values and how? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `PreferenceActivity` inherits from `ListActivity`. By default, `ListActivity` creates its own `ListView`, but you can supply your own layout via `setContentView()`, so long as your `ListView` in the layout has the right `android:id`. [Here is the layout](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/DeskClock.git;a=blob;f=res/layout/set_alarm.xml;h=466e8b71af30a145d63bb4d263595a3c3534731f;hb=HEAD) for the alarm activity.